# For what values of $a$ does $b\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: radicals, fractions, square-numbers, upper-lower-bounds, natural-numbers

I've the following function:

$$b=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{r-2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{r-3}{(r-2)^2}+\frac{a(1+a)}{r-2}+\frac{a(a^2-1)}{3}}$$

I know that:

- $\text{a}\ge1$ and $a\in\mathbb{N}$;
- $\text{r}\ge3$ and $r\in\mathbb{N}$.

> If I set the value of $r$, what does $a$ has to be in order to let $b\ge1$ and $b\in\mathbb{N}$? Are there restrictions on $a$ in order to let $b\ge1$ and $b\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Suggestions: Replace $r$ with $s = r-2$. Multiply both sides by $2s$. Subtract off $s-2$. Square both sides, cancel out any common terms, then work with what is left.(Renenber that the squaring may introduce false solutions.)

Comment: @PaulSinclair How does that help?

Comment: How does it not help?? If gives a much simpler equation without square roots or fractions (other than dividing $a(a^2-1)$ by $3$, which is always possible, since one of $a-1,a,a+1$ has to be divisible by $3$)). Then you can apply standard Diophantine equation techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Let $s = r - 2$. Then $$b=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{s}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{s - 1}{s^2}+\frac{a(1+a)}{r-2}+\frac{a(a^2-1)}{3}}$$ $$b = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{s}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{a(1+a)}{s}+\frac{a(a^2-1)}{3}}$$ $$b = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{s}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{s}\right)^2+\frac{a(1+a)}{s}+\frac{a(a^2-1)}{3}}$$.

Let $t = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{s}$ or $\frac{1}{s} = \frac{1}{2} - t$, such that $$b = t + \sqrt{t^2 - a(1 + a)t + \frac{a(1 + a)}{2} + \frac{a(1 + a)(a - 1)}{3}}$$
$$b = t + \sqrt{t^2 - a(1 + a)t + \frac{3a(1 + a) + 2(a - 1)a(1 + a)}{6}}$$
$$b = t + \sqrt{t^2 - 2t\frac{a(1 + a)}{2} + \frac{a(1 + a)(2a + 1)}{6}}$$
$$b = t + \sqrt{t^2 - 2t\sum_{i = 1}^{a} i + \sum_{i = 1}^{a} i^2}$$
As for all integers $a$, $$t < \sum_{i = 1}^{a} i$$
$$b = t + \sqrt{\left(-t + \sum_{i = 1}^{a} i\right)^2} = t - t + \sum_{i = 1}^{a} i = \sum_{i = 1}^{a} i = \frac{a(a + 1)}{2}$$

$b$ is only dependent upon $a$. If $a\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a \geq 1$, then $b\in \mathbb{N}$ and $b > 1$.